# Install plone add-on from source, instructions for complete newbie?

Tags: xmpp, plone, zope, add-on

Could anyone explain how to install the module below in a plone install?
I tried for 2 hours to no avail.

https://github.com/collective/collective.xmpp.chat

The instructions are too vague for a newbie. I have plone setup the docs in this repo seems incomplete and I'm totally lost on how to proceed. Any plone, zope and/or python guru could share some light on this?

Comment: If you are going to meddle with XMPP and Plone, you may also want to look into [`jarn.xmpp.core`](http://plone.org/products/jarn.xmpp.core).

Comment: thx @MartijnPieters Im not into plone im into the extension and want to see how things work, and then port it to a rails project and opensource it ( if author wich contacted agrees ) its license should not form an issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

General instructions for installing add-ons are at: https://plone.org/documentation/kb/installing-add-ons-quick-how-to.  To install things from source, the easiest way is to use "mr.developer" which is found and documented at: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer.

As you'll learn by reading that second document, you first need to add mr.developer to your buildout:

```
[buildout]
extensions = mr.developer
auto-checkout = name.of.your.product
```

then in the [sources] section, you tell mr. developer where to check out your product from.

```
[sources]
name.of.your.proudct = git git://github.com/url/of/name.of.your.product.git
```

finally, in the [eggs] section of your buildout, you tell plone to actually install the product.

```
[eggs]
name.of.your.product
```

Comment: thx this helps somewhat but could you outline how this would work in my specific case please?

Comment: Thx alot, this seems maybe like logic for you Plone guys but this was quite hard to figure out(not)

Comment: @Rubytastic you can also ask the maintainer to make a release